# How to get last compiled stage Procedure code in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

> Unfortunately i compiled my procedure with wrong code. is't possible
>   to get old compiled code in oracle.

Comment: No, Oracle only stores the source code of the currently compiled procedure not the historical versions of it. You should check the old version out of your version control system.... you are using a version control system aren't you?

Comment: you can use flashback query on dba_source. Or expdp with metadata_only and timestamp in the past. If you're lucky and there is no transactional activity in the database it might work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but if you are DBA and your server configured to using flashback queries you can try this:

```
select * 
  from dba_source AS OF TIMESTAMP 
   TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-14 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
 where upper(text) like '%PROCEDURE_YOU_LOOKING_FOR%'
```

And of course you choose timestamp you need

Comment: Thanks Leo. While  running above query i am getting this error. >[Error] Script lines: 1-4 --------------------------
 ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
 Script line 2, statement line 2, column 8

Comment: Login as DBA or sys user and then try,

Comment: If you are not DBA the only one way I guess - ask them for backups.